# MySQL and truncate

Tags: truncate, mysql

I just ran truncate statement on a table and committed. What options do I have to restore the table to the state pre truncate?

**Edit: I did this in my dev setup, hence nothing to worry for me, I was just curious to know do I have any options.**

Comment: restore your backup.

Comment: Further, if you don't have a backup, you're sunk - the data is gone.

Comment: Unless you've had binary logging enabled and have these logs avaialabl, in which case you can replay logs. But if you're asking this question, you most likely haven't.

Comment: Any good documents explaining how to replay logs? I know I can google this but if any of you off hand know anything good, then please point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably out of luck, sir. If you cannot restore from backup / replay logs (because you don't have them), then your next option is forensic recovery. That's beyond trying to explain. To succeed at that, you need to take the machine offline before anything else is written. Copy the whole disk if its MyISAM tables, or just the InnoDB files if it's InnoDB. Find an expert who can read the file internals and maybe you'll get it back.